I've been given a question on memory management using paging and dont know how to answer it

For part i) I got the answer of 16 bits by first calculating the number of frames and from the frame number I was then able to calculate the number. For part ii) I said the remaining bits are used for the address offset. Its now iii) that I'm really struggling with this because we haven't covered this within the content of my course and I'm unsure of how to continue.
